# Find a function given its properties

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

How do i find a function such as :

$\forall a,b,c \in \Bbb{R^3}$

$f(a)f(b)f(c)=f(\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2})f^2(0)$

Comment: How about $f\equiv0$?

Comment: Also $f\equiv1$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 1):

As proposed in the comments, consider the function $f\equiv0$. Then, for any $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}^3$ we have
$$ f(a)=f(b)=f(c)=0.$$
Obviously, this satisfies the equality 
$$ f(a)f(b)f(c)=f(\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2})f^2(0)$$
because both sides equal $0$ for any choice of $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 1):

The general soltution should be like $e^{f(0)+f(1)x^2+h(x)}$

First, choose $c=0$ the question is equilvalent to: $$f(a)f(b)=f(\sqrt{a^2+b^2})f(0)$$
Let $x=a/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, then
$$f(x)*f(\sqrt{1-x^2})=f(1)*f(0)$$
Let $g(x)=\ln f(x)$, then g satisfies:
$$g(x)+g(\sqrt{1-x^2})=g(1)+g(0)$$
Let $h(x)=g(x)-g(1)x^2-g(0)$, then $h(x)$ satisifes:
$$h(x)+h(\sqrt{1-x^2})=0$$
In fact, you can construct infinite continuous functions like $h$. A simple example could be $h=0$, another example could be:
\begin{equation}
 h=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{lc}
x-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} &  0<x<\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
-\sqrt{1-x^2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}  <x<1
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}